# babel-polyfill messed with Object in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I have a 1-year-old React app with Server Render that had been in production for a while,

However, it was detected a couple of days before that somehow, the app stop to work with IE11. This is really weird because we have been tested on IE11 many times and it worked before. We even try to roll back the project (using tagged docker image) and this error still appears.

The root cause appears to be in `babel-polyfill` that somehow change the way Object is created in IE11.

The created object will have `jscomp_symbol_Symbol.toStringTag1" Array Iterator"`

Here's what I found on the console:

[image]

try this input `console.log({})` if you have IE11 it will output differently.

This somehow causing my web app to fail since every object will fail lodash `_.isPlainObject` which is the condition inside `Redux`.

Comment: Can you check what version of `core-js` you're app is loading through `babel-polyfill`? And do you happen to be loading the Prototype.js library on your page somewhere? See https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/289. It should be fixed with `core-js@2.5.1` AFAIK.

Comment: the `babel-polyfill` is `6.26.0` which include `core-js@2.5.1`

Comment: We've been having the same issue, one day, pop, IE11 doesn't work due to this [object Array iterator] being the typeof a variable. Using react/webpack/babel as well, didn't seem to be caused by a top-level dependency version change. We've tried just about every version/ordering of babel-polyfill/core-js. Putt did you ever get to the bottom of this?